# Django change IntegerField to DecimalField on inherited model

Tags: django, inheritance, django-models

In Django I have 2 models that are inherited from an abstract base class. The base class has an IntegerField that I want to rename and change to DecimalField for some instances. There is a ForeignKey linking the 2 child models. I've read about model inheritance in docs, but there seems to be some [constraints](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#field-name-hiding-is-not-permitted). What's the best way to change the IntegerField to DecimalField?

```
class Parent(models.Model):
   intfield = models.IntegerField()
    
    class Meta:
        abstract=True
    

class Child1(Parent):
    addedfield = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    

class Child2(Parent):
    addedfield2 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    linked = models.ForeignKey(Child1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class GrandChild1(Child1):
    # change intfield to decimal


class GrandChild2(Child2):
    # change intfield to decimal
    # linked to GrandChild1 instead of Child1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use extra abstract models to alter the fields in the hierarchy:

```py
class Parent(models.Model):
   intfield = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class DescendantType1(Parent):
    """This is an abstract model that inherits from the Parent model, with the "type 1"
    attributes.
    """
    addedfield = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class DescendantType2(Parent):
    """This is an abstract model that inherits from the Parent model, with the "type 2"
    attributes.
    """
    addedfield2 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    linked = models.ForeignKey(
        "Child1",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        # This is required on foreign key fields in abstract models.
        # See the "Note about foreign key related names" below.
        related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related",
        related_query_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)ss",
    )

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Child1(DescendantType1):
    """A descendant with "type 1" attributes."""

class Child2(DescendantType2):
    """A descendant with "type 2" attributes."""

class GrandChild1(DescendantType1):
    intfield = models.DecimalField(...)

class GrandChild2(DescendantType2):
    intfield = models.DecimalField(...)
    linked = models.ForeignKey(
        "GrandChild1",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
```

#### Note about foreign key related names

An abstract model that has a foreign key needs to use a different `related_name` and `related_query_name` for each concrete model that inherits from it, otherwise the names for the *reverse* relationship would be the same for each subclass.

To handle this, django allows you to use template strings with the variables `app_label` and `class` so that the names are unique for the child model.

You can find [more about this in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name-and-related-query-name).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I tried to create migrations using Child1 as ForeignKey on DescendentType2 it generated an error. `NameError 'Child1' is not defined.

Comment: I moved it to the child model, and it worked.

Comment: That's weird. Did you change `"Child1"` from a string (by removing the quotes)? It should still be able to reference the model if it doesn't exist yet. I could be wrong though. It may also be specific to django migrations.

Comment: You're right, I accidentally missed the quotes. If I change it on the abstract class it means all the related references are renamed. Changing the child model seemed to keep everything working on the front end.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to the benefits of using Child1 on the abstract model. If the related query is refactored, I'm guessing that you could use the existing templates for all child classes. If linked is redefined on the child class would it need new templates?

Comment: Using the `linked` foreign key to `Child1` on the abstract model allows for more than 1 model to subclass `DescendantType2` and always contain the `linked`/`addedfield2` fields. If for your purposes, you only have a single model that has a `linked` fk to `Child1`, then it's not especially helpful and it makes sense to move `linked` to the concrete model (the child class with `abstract = False`).